Lubuntu takes time to connect to wifi
I installed the latest version of lubuntu. it takes time to connect to wifi. not sure what is the issue. wifi will work when i use wifi dongle.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour]. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status.
